# Can I somehow make my vector/array dynamically change number of dimentions?

Tags: c++

I need an option to change dimentions of my vector or array. I mean I am trying to get an option where I can get a number of dimentions ex. from a file and then create vector or array with that number of dimentions.

When I write

```
int **array = new int*array
```

or

```
vector< vector <int> > vec
```

I already define number of dimentions. Can I get dynamic dimentions in c++? If not is there any language where I can do this?

Edit: I want to get number from file let's say it's X and then in my code I would like to create X dimentional array.
For example if it's 2 then

```
vector<vector <int> > vec
```

if it's 3 then

```
vector<vector<vector <int> > > vec
```

Comment: So you want to turn a 1d array or single `vector` into a 2d array or `vector`? (e.g. you have `std::vector<int>` but you then need `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?)

Comment: Or do you size? Like you have an array / `vector` of size 10, but upon reading a file need more?

Comment: Recommend an edit adding something along the lines of, "I start with this <example goes here>, and I want to end with <example goes here>." Right now there's a bunch of different ways this question can be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

An array with one dimension can act like it's multi-dimensional.

For example, instead of `int multi_dimensional_array[2][3][4];` you could write `int single_dimensional_array[2 * 3 * 4];`

Then, to access the elements, `multi_dimensional_array[i1][i2][i3];` becomes `single_dimensional_array[(i1 * 3 * 4) + (i2 * 4) + i3];`

You can apply the same thing to your problem: write `int* ptr = new int[...];` with whatever the number and size of the dimensions are.